# Group coordinator is unavailable or invalid

Tags: java, php, apache-kafka

I can not connect to kafka.
A colleague says that you don’t need to specify a group, but on the php client I can’t do this.

I get an error on Java:

`Group coordinator ###.###.###.###:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery`

On the php:

`SyncGroupRequest failed: Broker: Group coordinator not available: actions Refresh`

Is this a problem on the receiver or sender side?

Comment: php-rdkafka? Yes, you can set a group id https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.examples-high-level-consumer.html